# Near real-time replication of Wordpress blogs

Tags: ubuntu, vps, cron, rsync, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog that is currently residing on a server (VPS) in UK and I would like to set up an identical server (same specs, same OS - Ubuntu) for some sort of redundancy as well as fail-safe.

I know it is possible to set up rSync + Cron for content replication and MySQL Master-Master replication for DB, however honestly after spending the whole night trying to configure the MySQL replication, I am really reluctant to continue any further.

Therefore, is there any solution that is sort of pre-pacakged that I can just run to achieve the kind of set up I need? I have root access to both VPS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need master-master schema?

Comment: because I was hoping that someone visiting my website in US would be going to US server and visiting in EU would be using UK server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think you are starting at the wrong level. Are there any tools at the application (wordpress) level? Maybe something like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/copy-post/ would work. Otherwise there seem to be some OK hits when I searched for "sync wordpress blog" or "replicate wordpress blog."

Second, I wouldn't do multi-master replication. I'd create a slave mysql installation. Point both wordpress installations at the master. If the master fails then promote the slave to master. The wordpress installation that doesn't use the local DB would be slower, maybe unacceptably slow.

Third, though these techniques provide redundancy (availability) they do not provide fail-safe (backup). E.g., if you accidentally deleted a post on one installation the post would be deleted on the other.

Comment: That looks more like a master-slave replication set up though rather than a master-master replication...but I will give that a shot and will keep everyone posted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just do master/slave replication plus rsync and point all traffic to your master side.